# How to Use select2.js

Tags: jquery, html, jquery-chosen, jquery-select2

I want to add a form field which can auto fill text & can take multiple tabs(similar to fb).
I found select2.js helps me do it, But i am having problems in using it when i set multiple attribute to true. if i add multiple: true, the page dispalys it as a normal select.

I find documentation on select2  page confusing.

I am a new to all of them, Please help me out.

```
<html>
<head>
<script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>          
<script type="text/javascript" src="select2.js"></script>          

 <link href="select2.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
    <script src="select2.js"></script>
    <script>
        $(document).ready(function() { 
        $("#e1").select2([multiple: true]);
        });
    </script>

</head>
<body>
<input type="button" id="123">click
</br>
<input type="hidden" id="1234">
<select id="e1">
        <option value="AL">Alabama</option>
        <option value="Am">Amalapuram</option>
        <option value="An">Anakapalli</option>
        <option value="Ak">Akkayapalem</option>

        <option value="WY">Wyoming</option>
    </select>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: here is example tutorial https://youtu.be/gTNQOxvuUv0

Answer (score 25):

Add the attribute "multiple", and a width as well, only in the markup.

```
<select multiple id="e1" style="width:300px">
```

and js as this:

```
$(document).ready(function() { 
 $("#e1").select2();
});
```

See fiddle here: http://jsfiddle.net/marcusasplund/jEADR/2/

A side note; you are loading select2.js 2 times in the code posted in your question.

Comment: This worked for me on CakePHP.  Spent forever trying to figure out what magic they worked on the select2 git...Thank You.

Comment: @mattblang You are right, maybe the bit "only in the markup" was a bit confusing. It might be better to specify a width in the css. Might be, as you have to set the width on the container constructed by select2 as this:

`.select2-container-multi {
    width: 300px
}`

Then, if one does not specify a width at all on the targeted select element, the select2 element will start with only 2*5px padding and 0px width = 10px. And it is perhaps a bit small for a good UX. 

Updated fiddle here: [link](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/318/)

Comment: Set the selected attribute on the option you want as initial value:

`<option value="Am" selected>Amalapuram</option>`
See fiddle here:[http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/326/](http://jsfiddle.net/jEADR/326/)

Answer (score 1):

You can override the class specific for select2.js:

```
.select2-container-multi .select2-choices {
    width: 150px;
}
```

It should work.

Answer (score 1):

**You can use use multiple attribute with select**

```
 <html>
  <head>
    <link href="select2.min.css" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css">
    <script type="text/javascript" src="jquery.js"></script>      
    <script type="text/javascript" src="select2.min.js"></script>     
 </head>
 <body>
    <select multiple id="getCountry">
      <option value="India">India</option>
      <option value="Afghanistan">Afghanistan</option>
      <option value="japan">japan</option>
    </select>
    <input type="button" id="submit" value="Submit">click
    <script>
      $(document).ready(function() {   
        $("#getCountry").select2();   
      });      
    </script>   
  </body>
</html>
```